# Spring CSRF Token & API Resource

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I'm having some trouble understanding CSRF tokens. I'm building a simple HATEOAS service with no front end.

Spring Java config enables CSRF by default. Where in the documentation can I find details on how to get the token?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want csrf protection (normally you don't for an API resource) you can set `http.csrf().disable()`. (Standard Spring Security. I'm sure it's in the docs.)